# Idea i github как сделать отдельные папки с проектами?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, github

При добавлении проекта на github через ide появляется окошко, где можно указать только название проекта, в итоге он пишет в корень.
Можно ли как-то писать проекты в отдельные папки?
Patterns(общая папка) и внутри, к примеру, три папки: Abstract Factory Pattern, Factory Pattern, Singleton Pattern?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду разные проекты - в один репозиторий git, только в разные папки? Проще объедините ваши проекты в один, разнесите по пакетам и используйте один репозиторий.

Comment: Я не понимаю что значит разнести по пакетам))) хоть бы кто объяснил)

Comment: @Александр объясните пожалуйста, что вы понимаете под словом "проекты". Например, "Abstract Factory Pattern" это проект? Это самостоятельная программа какая-то?

Comment: Ну смотрите. У вас у примеру два проекта, верно? В одном есть класс А, в другом класс Б. Сделайте в проекте А пакеты(java package) com.example1, com.example2. В пакет com.example1 поместите ваш класс А, в com.example2 поместите ваш класс Б. В итоге у вас будет ОДИН проект с двумя классами, которые разнесены по пакетам

Comment: Ну примерно понял)) в intellij idea есть создать package и так в проекте может быть 2 main, на javarush так задания сделаны)

Comment: @Nick Volynkin ♦, программы, со своим main, которые друг с другом не связаны, в них могут повторятся классы, но будут по-разному реализованы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы имеете ввиду разные проекты - в один репозиторий git, только в разные папки? Проще объедините ваши проекты в один, разнесите по пакетам и используйте один репозиторий. – Chubatiy 8 июл в 6:10

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал так.
D:\Patterns\ Abstract Factory Pattern.gitattributes|.gitignore|.git\
D:\Patterns\Factory Pattern.gitattributes|.gitignore|.git\
D:\Patterns\Singleton Pattern.gitattributes|.gitignore|.git\

В итоге получается корневая папка Patterns и в ней 3 ваших проекта, внутри которого уже пакеты. Если в этом вопрос был.